# Compare vs Radix

Tags: sorting, comparison, radix-sort

Is it better to use comparison or radix sort to sort a long sequences of java int array?

I know that I should probably use mergesort (NlogN) for comparison sort, since it is one of the fastest and compare that to LSD or MSD. I thought about how for extremely large N, the logarithm would be larger than runtime for LSD, but other than that, the mergesort (comparison) is better.

I wonder if my reasoning is correct because I have seen a question asking about Strings and the answer was the aforementioned. Now this question is about long sequences of java int array and I wonder if I am missing the point.

Any help is appreciated :).

Comment: You should use the native sorting routine.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: Thanks for answering! May I have your reasoning?

Comment: The native sorting routine is usually optimized, and so would probably be faster than any naive implementation of whatever sorting algorithm. In the case of Java, it might be (though I doubt it) that it is implemented in native code rather than bytecode.

Comment: When in doubt, benchmark. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory sorting a long sequence of int should be a prime candidate for radix sort as it grows linear in the number of elements to be sorted, while any comparison based sorting algorithm can't be faster than N log N.

Comment: Thanks! The explanation is what I really needed. I need someone else to confirm with!

Comment: Note that this will be better in the Big-O sense, but it's possible that a Quicksort or Mergesort will be faster in practice due to smaller constants. The only way to know is to test.